# Calling action from main class init()

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

I'm trying to call an action from my main class in Craft 3. This is working fine with my services like this:

```
AbandonedCart::$plugin->serviceExample->serviceMethod();
```

I've tried to do something similar for my action but it doesn't work and I can't find any solution to it.

```
AbandonedCart::$plugin->actionExample->actionFunction();
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your `setComponents` function before you are trying to access your components otherwise - logically - they are not defined

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    self::$plugin = $this;

    // define the components / services
    $this->setComponents(
        [
            'serviceExample' => ServiceExample::class
        ];
    );

    // access them
    $this->serviceExample->serviceMethod();
    // if it's easier for you to remember you can as well use the longer/slower syntax
    AbandonedCart::$plugin->serviceExample->serviceMethod();
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this is indeed a better version of what I used. I had to use `services\ServiceExample::class` to get it working with my services. This however doesn't work for actions in my controller. I get the following error: `Missing required parameter "id" when instantiating "abandonedcart\abandonedcart\controllers\DefaultController".`

Comment: Why would you even call a controller action in your `init` function in the first place? That's not intended and bad practice. Controllers are for handling requests and you should route to those actions based on request parameters.

Comment: It's for testing an action that'll be triggered by an Ajax request. But I'll test with a service in the mean time. Thanks!